# XSLT for a particular XML Format

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to create an XSL to better display an XML document that is automatically created by a process within my organization.

I'm trying to render it as so developers can reference the information within.
I apologize but I am new to XSLT and trying to apply tutorials to my scenario.

Ideally for my first go round, I am trying to list out the /DCXT/ATRs/ATR nodes and their attribute values.  I will progress from there.

Right now all I can get using this XLST and chrome (opened via the appropriate command to allow local xsl files) is the header text and the column titles.

I get on row that has no values in it.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

The XML format is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ques.xsl"?>

<DCXT attr1="xxx" attr2="yyyy" attr3="zzzz">
    <Desc>Text description</Desc>
    <dbc>
        <drv>text for drv</drv>
        <prm/>
        <hsNode>text for hsNode</hsNode>
        <ptNode>text for ptNode</ptNode>
        <sName>text for sname</sName>
        <prd/>
    </dbc>
    <DSPs attr4="aaaa" attr5="1" attr3="bbb">
        <dsp attr6="1" attr7="true" attr8="1">
            <Desc>text for desc</Desc>
        </dsp>
        <!--... multiple 'Dsp' nodes defined defined ...-->
    </DSPs>
    <ATRs>
        <ATR attr9="true" attr10="text for attr">
            <FRs>
                <FR attr11="xxx" attr12="text for attr">
                    <MPs>
                        <MP attr13="xxx" attr14="yyyy"/>
                        <!-- .... multiple MP nodes defined -->
                    </MPs>
                </FR>
                <!--... multiple FR nodes defined ...-->
            </FRs>
            <DPY>
                <RDFs>
                    <SOF attr15="xxx" attr16="0"/>
                </RDFs>
                <BFRs>
                    <sof attr17="xxx" attr18="0"/>
                </BFRs>
            </DPY>
        </ATR>
        <!-- multiple ATR nodes defined -->
    </ATRs>
    <!-- more nodes defined at this level but removing for brevity-->
</DCXT>
```

My text XSL is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My Text XSL</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>attr9</th>
        <th>attr10</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="/DCXT">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="attr9"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="attr10"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A little more detail on exactly what is wrong and where you are having trouble will improve your question a good deal, which will (hopefully) lead to an answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your text says you want to process `/DCXT/ATRs/ATR` so I would change `<xsl:for-each select="/DCXT">` to `<xsl:for-each select="/DCXT/ATRs/ATR">` and then use `@attribute-name` inside, that is, change

```
     <td><xsl:value-of select="attr9"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="attr10"/></td>
```

to

```
     <td><xsl:value-of select="@attr9"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@attr10"/></td>
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem was I was not getting any rows in my table.
While I did have the wrong navigation path in my select statement, that was a typo as I had tried that prior.  The real problem was that I was not including the '@' in front of the attribute name.

Thanks for helping out with such a newbie quesiton.